# How to Process Large Size Data Using Multiple Threads In Snowflake Procedure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

my requirement is ; I have large size of data available in Snowflake and i would like to process the data using multi thread in JavaScript Based Procedure; the data available is independent of each other; basically there is no inter dependency ; so in order to reduce the processing time i would like to process this data in multiple threads.
Do you know how this can be done using multi thread option in JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the stored procedures API for JavaScript doesn't support async queries or multi-threading (for now).

An alternative is to use a tree of Snowflake tasks - as one task can have multiple dependents those will be executed in parallel.

Here's the proof with a minimal example:

- https://github.com/fhoffa/snowflake_snippets/blob/main/stream_and_tasks/prove_parallelism.sql

In this example I created two queries that take 10 seconds to run each. By having both as parallel tasks in a tree, you can see that they executed at the same time:

[image]

You can see that both queries took 10 seconds to produce 5 billion rows each, and then inserted a new row within the same sub-second.

Comment: thanks @Felipe Hoffa for your quick response.

Comment: Thanks! Btw, check my updated answer than includes a way to have multiple queries run in parallel by leveraging tasks,